# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

I am using hibernate 5 with orcale 12c and java 9
When i execute this code error occur hibernate could not execute statement

I wrote easy program at Hibernate and caught bunch of exception .

I couldn't find out what the exactly thing is wrong.

I have three classes - student, main and hibernate.cfg,xml.

this is very simple hibernate code which involve only one class which is student class

#### STUDENT.JAVA

```
package hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
//@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_Name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_Name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {

    }
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
        <property name="connection.username">scott</property>
        <property name="connection.password">tiger</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

### main class

```
package hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class ClassStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        //create session

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            //create student object
            System.out.println("creating new Student object...");
            Student tempStudent = new Student("sohaib","ahmed","sohaibahmedawan@gmail.com");

            //start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            //save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student....");
            session.save(tempStudent);

            ///commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!!!");
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }

    }
```

### error

```
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:27 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.1.Final}
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:27 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl]
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=scott}
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:29 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
creating new Student object...
Saving the student....
Hibernate: insert into Student (email, first_Name, last_Name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Jan 24, 2019 12:36:31 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
Jan 24, 2019 12:36:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1490)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:515)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3348)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2519)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at hibernate.demo.ClassStudentDemo.main(ClassStudentDemo.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3175)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3689)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1484)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in  stacktrace clearly says that the table is not found.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

So you can either create a table in your schema in oracle db or tell hibernate to create the table at the time of creation of session factory .

You can include the below property in your hibernate configuration file

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

So hibernate will create a table for you.

Also, you need to annotate your entity class with @Table attribute
I see that line is commented in your code

```
@Entity
//@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
```

Comment: @SohaibAhmed have you mapped that table to your entity class ? by annotating with @Table(name="Exact table Name here")

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue - This error is because your dependencies are not compatible with each other.

```
Use the below dependencies and the error should be gone. 

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>`enter code here`
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
     <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/antlr-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5H3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/el-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error is generated when someone using latest version of hibernate.

In order to resolve it, simply go to `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and change dialect according to your version. In my case, I am using version 5 in MySQL Workbench.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Only Change done is:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

from

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```